# Remove Auto-generated URL Rewrites

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog, url, url-rewrite

I've been having this issue with auto-generated URLs. The catalog/* URLs keep auto-generating the red box are the URLs that auto-generate, the green box are the URLs that I want. How do I stop the red box URLs from auto-generating? I just deleted a 100 auto-generated catalog/* URLs manually, but more URL's keep getting generated. Please help.

[image: Magento URL Rewrites]

[image: SEO Configuration]